# Figuring out the plan to write an RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a controller as following:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html
  def show
    client = ReportServices::Client.new(ServiceConfig['reports_service_uri'])
    @report = client.population_management(params[:id])
    if @report
      @kpis = @report[:key_performance_indicators]
      @populations = @report[:population_scores]
      @population_summaries = @report[:population_summaries]
      @providers = @report[:provider_networks]
    end
    respond_with (@report)   
  end
end
```

Which I want to write a RSpec test for it but have no clue where to start from, I guess because it has that URL in it, it makes it harder for me, I am pretty new to Rails and RSpec and have some basic knowledge of writing RSpec for my Models but this one has puzzled me for the whole weekend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing to tackle is mocking the external API request. The general idea here is that your going to return a mock object from new that will respond to population_management and return what you expect for @report.

```
describe ReportsController do
  before do
    @report_data = {
      :key_performance_indicators => 'value',
      :population_scores => 'value',
      :population_summaries => 'value',
      :provider_networks => 'value'
    }
    # This will fake the call to new, return a mock object that when
    # population_management is called will return the hash above.
    @fake_client = double(:population_management => @report_data)
    ReportServices::Client.stub(:new => @fake_client)
  end

  describe '#show' do
    it 'assigns @report' do
      get :show, id: 1
      assigns(:report).should == @report
    end

    it 'assigns some shortcut vars' do
      [:kpis, :populations, :population_summaries, :providers].each do |var|
        assigns(var).should_not be_nil
      end
    end

    # and whatever else you'd like
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stub the client interface to write an isolated test of your controller.

```
describe RerpotsController do
  it "assigns a new report as @report" do
    expected_id = '1234'
    expected_kpi = 'kpi'

    report = { key_performance_indicators: expected_kpi, ... }
    client = double(ReportServices::Client)
    client.should_receive(:population_management).with(expected_id) { report }
    ReportServices::Client.should_receive(:new) { client }

    get :show, id: expected_id

    assigns(:kpis).should eq(expected_kpi)
    # ...
  end
end
```

You probably don't need to unpack the report in the controller.